# What's the best way to earn "Demolition Man" trophy?

Tags: achievements, battlefield-bad-company-2

I'm replaying through Battlefield: Bad Company 2 on my PS3 at the moment and want to unlock the last trophies I missed during my first playthroughs (mostly MP trophies). I've got one trophy which seems to be kinda difficult to get:

> **Demolition Man:** Online: get 20 demolish kills

What's the best way to achieve this trophy? I tried playing as an engineer with RPG or recon with C4 and blow up every building (or at least *prepare* it to collapse it with a grenade or something), but it's very difficult to get demolish kill.

Can you give me some advice for getting this trophy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to go about getting this achievement is to use C4. **Play the Rush game mode**, because you can blow up some of the buildings with the bomb in it and they will be high traffic areas during the game. Then **place C4 on the four corners and on the ceiling of the first floor**. This should be enough to collapse the building. Remember to be patient, this is one of the hardest achievements in the game and will take some time. You will kill people with your C4 and not the destruction 2.0 and you can't avoid that happening. Just keep trying and eventually you will get the achievement.

If you like visual references, here's a guide on youtube to help you out

> 